# Spring AntPathMatcher with a custom separator behaves strangely

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ant, pattern-matching

I face a problem with [`AntPathMatcher`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html) of Spring Boot version `2.5.5`. I assume the Ant matcher should return `true` if the `pattern` and `path` are equal and none of them contains Ant-specific characters (i.e. let's say it contains only alphanumeric characters).

The following lines demonstrate the assumption failure:

```java
new AntPathMatcher().match("consent", "consent");             // true
new AntPathMatcher().match("consentreg", "consentreg");       // true

new AntPathMatcher("\\t").match("consent", "consent");        // true
new AntPathMatcher("\\t").match("consentreg", "consentreg");  // false
```

Do I assume the behavior wrongly? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use multi-character separators with `AntPathMatcher`. The path separator is passed to [`StringUtils.tokenizeToStringArray(String, String, boolean, boolean)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/StringUtils.html#tokenizeToStringArray-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-boolean-boolean-) as the `delimiters` argument. This argument is described as "the delimiter characters, assembled as a `String` (each of the characters is individually considered as a delimiter)". In its current form, your code is telling `AntPathMatcher` to use `\` and `t` as path separators. As a result, `consentreg` is split into two strings: `consen` and `reg`.

Perhaps you meant to use a tab character as the separator:

```java
new AntPathMatcher("\t").match("consentreg", "consentreg");  // true
```